# Get the "most" optimal row in a JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

## Problem

I have a situation in which I have two tables in which I would like the entries from table 2 (lets call it table_2) to be matched up with the entries in table 1 (table_1) such that there are no duplicates rows of table_2 used in the match up.

## Discussion

Specifically, in this case there are datetime stamps in each table (field is utcdatetime).  For each row in table_1, I want to find the row in table_2 in which has the closed utcdatetime to the table 1 utcdatetime such that the table2.utcdatetime is older than the table_1 utcdatetime and within 30 minutes of the table 1 utcdatetime.  Here is the catch, I do not want any repeats.  If a row in table 2 gets gobbled up in a match on an earlier row in table 1, then I do not want it considered for a match later.

This has currently been implemented in a Python routine, but it is slow to iterate over all of the rows in table 1 as it is large.  I thought I was there with a single SQL statement, but I found that my current SQL results in duplicate table 2 rows in the output data.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and desired output?

Comment: So you need all records from `table_1` and the closest record from `table_2` for it. You also don't want `table_2` records to be output several times. What should be output in case the record from `table_2` that is closest to some record from `table_1` has already been assigned to another `table_1` record? NULL, or next best match should be found?

Comment: It should be next best match.  I am thinking that I just need to add one more level to my current query which would group by on the table_2 pk and then min on the delta time.  More to come here.

Comment: @Sergey Yes, I would agree with you.  Let me try this one thing and then if that does not work I will try to provide more details.

Comment: So, to be clear, if we've got two rows in table 2 that are older than 2 rows in table 1, but they're all well within a 30 minute window, the "closest" pair of table1 and table 2 rows pair up and then the earliest t2/latest t1 are paired, correct?

Comment: If so, it seems obvious that you cannot determine which row may match a given row in table 1 without already knowing all previous results, which unfortunately puts us in Row by Agonizing Row territory, e.g. using a cursor or similar.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result, to your question. As it is, the question is not clear [to me].

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a nested select to get whatever results you're looking for.
For instance:

```
select *
from person p
where p.name_first = 'SCCJS'
and not exists (select 'x' from person p2 where p2.person_id != p.person_id
                and p.name_first = 'SCCJS' and p.name_last = 'SC')
```